# Why is it ok to declare a class name in template param list

Tags: c++

This [Chromium doc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/styleguide/c++/blink-c++.md#Prefer-enums-or-StrongAliases-to-bare-bools-for-function-parameters) offers a weird code snippet:

```cpp
using ForReload = base::StrongAlias<class ForReloadTag, bool>;
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                    it compiles, though not declared anywhere
```

where `StrongAlias` is defined as ([source code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:base/types/strong_alias.h)):

```cpp
// TagType is an empty tag class (also called "phantom type") that only serves
// the type system to differentiate between different instantiations of the
// template.
...
template <typename TagType, typename UnderlyingType>
class StrongAlias {
 public:
  constexpr StrongAlias() = default;
  constexpr explicit StrongAlias(const UnderlyingType& v) : value_(v) {}
  ...
};
```

Why is it OK to say `class ForReloadTag` in the template param list when instantiating `StrongAlias`? Is this some kind of forward declaration (but it's not defined later)?

Comment: I was unable to find a description for that usage in the C++17 standard 17.7 "Template instantiation and specialization", but I'm sure this construct is valid C++17 (tried myself).

Comment: This is called an [elaborated type specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to the way C++ grammar works, instead of something like `foo`, you can say `class foo`:

```cpp
foo f1;        // valid
class foo f2;  // also valid
```

This can be used to disambiguate when there is a variable of that name in the scope:

```cpp
int foo;      // variable
class foo f1; // class, not the variable.
```

And a weird thing is, when you use this feature, if the class isn't declared *anywhere*, it will forward declare it for you:

```cpp
void bar(class foo* fp);
```

This will compile even if class `foo` isn't declared anywhere. You can apparently use that for templates too:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct foo{};


int main() {
  auto f = foo<class bar>{}; // bar isn't declared anywhere
}
```

---

It's called an [elaborated type specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier). You can see [this CppCon talk](https://youtu.be/tsG95Y-C14k?t=241) for more oddities in C++ grammar.

Comment: Wow. I didn't know about this.

Comment: Whoops, it looks `class bar` forward-declared this way leaks out to the global scope: https://godbolt.org/z/qTGKEj